# Detach Silverlight 4 Out-of-Browser Window

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-oob

I'm writing a Silverlight OOB application.  Once the user has installed it, I would like the in-browser experience, on next visit, to just have a button to launch the OOB version.  I know the API call to detect that it's installed, but I'm not sure to open my main Page control as or within a Window.  Currently my in-browser view changes to say "Please launch from the installed shortcut" but that seems like it should be unnecessary.  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately launching OOB app from the web page is not supported. This is commonly requested feature, but it looks like SL5 is not going to address it.

Comment: That is not cool.  Thanks for the response though.  I spent way too long looking for what I assumed was there!